# Possible memory leak in apps script array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm building a Google Docs add on that pulls data from Jira.

The response object (issueMeta in the code below) is a JSON nested array with > 500,000 lines in it. The response object exists. I filter thru it to find an object with type.name === "Epic", which I've verified exists in the response data.

However on the last line I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined", so it sounds like epicFields is not being set in the filter function.

I'm wondering if its a memory leak issue. Any ideas?

```
  const issueMeta = getIssueMeta();
  let epicFields = issueMeta.filter(function (type) {
      return type.name === "Epic"
  });
  epicFields = epicFields[0].fields;
```

Comment: Will be good if you make a `console.log` to `issueMeta`, maybe no object has "Epic" in "name". In that case, the `epicFields` must be an empty array and `epicFields[0]` should be `undefined`. So, `epicFields[0].fields` must fail.

Comment: Thanks, looking into it

Comment: Without being able to actually see the json or at least the relevant portion I doubt that anyone can help you.  All that we know for sure is that `epicFields[0]` is undefined.   While your example probably meets the minimal requirement it does not allow us to reproduce the problem and thus makes it near impossible for us to provide a solutioin.